# Delphi Calculate age of person from TDateEdit component

Tags: datetime, delphi, date-arithmetic

I have a very simple form with a `TDateEdit`, `TButton` and `TLabel` component.
[image]

What is the best way to get the age of someone if the date given is their birthdate? How would someone do this in Delphi from the `TDateEdit` component and then display the age within the label?

Is there maybe a built in function or something I can use to get the age of someone from their date of birth in the component? I'm looking for the simplest, easiest and best way to do this.

Comment: Be careful using [**YearsBetween**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.DateUtils.YearsBetween) function, as it can say someone is 18 when they are in fact still 17.

Comment: @IanBoyd When would it show 18 when in fact the person is still 17?

Comment: *"Thus, for example, YearsBetween reports the difference between January 1 and December 31 as 0 on non-leap years and 1 on leap years."* Substitute January 1 17 years ago, and today is December 31 of a leap year, and you have a 17 year old being counted as 18. It's similar to the SQL Server `datediff` function; it counts the number of interval **crossings**, rather than a difference of dates.

Comment: YearsBetween simply divides the period between the parameters by 365.25 days. It will fail in many edge cases when near the birthday.  Consider someone whose 18th birthday is today, 28-May-2019, born 28-May-2001.  YearsBetween takes the age in days, 6574, and divides by 365.25 to get 17.9986310746064, and returns 17.   Ian Boyd's answer will give the correct result.

Comment: Subtract one year from the other. Subtract one if the date within the year has not been reached.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with firemonkey?

Comment: @J... TDateEdit is a FireMonkey component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a function to calculate someone's age.

It is distinctly different from the RTL function [**YearsBetween**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.DateUtils.YearsBetween), as that calculates the number of years between two dates; and is fundamentally not the same as someone's age.

```
function GetAge(const BirthDate, CurrentDate: TDateTime): Integer;
var
    y1, m1, d1: Word; //born
    y2, m2, d2: Word; //today
begin
    Result := 0;

    if CurrentDate < BirthDate then
        Exit;

    DecodeDate(BirthDate, y1, m1, d1);
    DecodeDate(CurrentDate, y2, m2, d2);

    //Fudge someone born on the leap-day to Feb 28th of the same year
    //strictly for the purposes of this calculation
    if ( (m1=2) and (d1=29) )
            and
        ( not IsLeapYear(y2) ) then
    begin
        d1 := 28;
    end;

    Result := y2-y1; //rough count of years
    //Take away a year of the month/day is before their birth month/day
    if (m2 < m1) or
            ((m2=m1) and (d2<d1)) then
        Dec(Result);
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like the simplest and easiest way at all.

Comment: @kobik Maybe it's code only, but there are comments that explain functionality quite clearly, I would probably just add why to use this function instead of YearsBetween.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function YearsBetween() from the System.DateUtils unit to calculate the number of years between today (which you get from the function now) and the date in your `TDateEdit` component, which you get from the date property.

```
Label1.Text:= Trunc(YearsBetween(Now,DateEdit1.Date)).toString;
```

Comment: You cannot use YearsBetween to calculate a person's age.  Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Ian Boyd's answer, but for those that insist that YearsBetween is the way to go, here's an alternative.

If Y is the result from YearsBetween, then the proper result is either Y or Y+1.  This routine calls YearsBetween and returns Y+1.  Then it uses IncYear to see if the answer is too big.  If it is, it returns Y.

This might seem like it's simpler, but behind the scenes there is a lot more work going on.  Ian Boyd's answer is the one you should use.

```
function AgeInCompleteYears ( const nBirthDate   : tDateTime;
                              const nCurrentDate : tDateTime  ) : integer;
begin
  Result := 1 + DateUtils.YearsBetween ( nCurrentDate, nBirthDate );
  if DateUtils.IncYear ( nBirthDate, Result ) > nCurrentDate then
    dec ( Result );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetAge(BirthDate:TDateTime; RefDate:TDateTime=0):Integer;
begin
  if RefDate=0 then RefDate:= Today;
  Result := Trunc((RefDate- BirthDate) / 365.25)
end;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the ".25" supposed to be?

Comment: @MartynA My guess would be to account for the leap-day (29 February), which only exists every 4 years.

Comment: Hi @MarcGuillot.  Yes, I thought it might be something like that, but that seems to overlook the fact that not every fourth year is a leap year.  Anyway, let's hear what the OP has to say.